# tikzpicture scaling of x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

LaTex users.

I am trying to replicate the graph grid and some straight line graphs, shown in the diagram below. As you can see, the the x-axis of the graph (of range 0 to 30) has been adjusted so that the x-axis is looking too wide.
[image: correct image]

However, the code I am working with which is the folllowing

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\pagecolor{blue!13}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0.1cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{web}{RGB}{56, 102, 166}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[middle grid style/.style={lightgray,line width=0.5pt}]
\pgfplotsset{%
    % enable layer, needed to draw middle grid below axis
    set layers=standard,
    % disable ticks
    every major tick/.style={draw=none},
    every minor tick/.style={draw=none},
}
\begin{axis}    [
axis lines = {center},
% set fixed scale to get mm grid
% note: this is for the major grid
x=1cm,
y=1cm,
ylabel = {$y$},
xlabel = {$x$},
ytick distance = 1,
xtick distance = 5,
% number of minor ticks between 2 major ticks
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=9,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=5.8,
xmin=-0.6,
xmax=30.5,
major grid style={lightgray,thick},
minor grid style={lightgray,very thin},
grid=both,
axis line style={thick},
]

% draw middle grid
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid}
\foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5,...,4.5}{
    % \edef-trick, see manual page 541
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[middle grid style]
        (axis cs:\x,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
        (axis cs:\x,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});}
    \temp
}
%               v-- first, second and last y-positions for middle grid
\foreach \y in {-0.5,0.5,...,10.5}{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[middle grid style]
        (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\y) --
        (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\y);}
    \temp
}
\end{pgfonlayer}

%\addplot    [mark = none, domain= 0:10, smooth]{1.1*x};
\node[below] at (-0.2,0) {$O$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the graph with very wide x-axis as shown below:

[image: incorrect]

What changes do I need make in the code to achieve what I want?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x=1cm` is clearly to blame, it gives you 1cm for every axis unit, so the axis becomes 30cm wide. If you want to more or less exactly replicate that, I'd set `scale only axis,width=6cm,height=5cm`, and change the axis limits to `xmin=0,xmax=30,ymin=0,ymax=5`. You can use `shorten >=-3mm` in the `axis line style` to extend the axis lines a bit.

(The screenshot doesn't show the middle lines,but they're there, zoom the PDF to see.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, layoutvoffset=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{pgfplots} %loaded above
%\usepackage{amsmath} % loaded by mathtools
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
%\usepackage{tikz} % loaded by pgfplots
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{bigints}
%\usepackage{color} % loaded by tikz
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % don't you want any indication of new paragraphs?
%\pagecolor{blue!13}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
%\voffset = 0.1cm % I think it's generally better to use the geometry package for all such things
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{web}{RGB}{56, 102, 166}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % you did this a few lines ago
%\setcounter{page}{1} %why?


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[middle grid style/.style={lightgray,line width=0.5pt}]
\pgfplotsset{%
    % enable layer, needed to draw middle grid below axis
    set layers=standard,
    % disable ticks
    every major tick/.style={draw=none},
    every minor tick/.style={draw=none},
}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = {center},
% set width of axis box
scale only axis,
width=6cm,
height=5cm,
ylabel = {$y$},
xlabel = {$x$},
ytick distance = 1,
xtick distance = 5,
% number of minor ticks between 2 major ticks
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=9,
% all axis limits are modified
ymin=0,
ymax=5,
xmin=0,
xmax=30,
major grid style={lightgray,thick},
minor grid style={lightgray,very thin},
grid=both,
axis line style={thick, shorten >=-3mm, line cap=rect},
clip mode=individual, % so that the $O$ node isn't clipped
ylabel style={above left, yshift=3pt},
xlabel style={above right}
]

% draw middle grid
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid}
\foreach \x in {2.5,7.5,...,27.5}{ % <-- modified these values
    % \edef-trick, see manual page 541
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[middle grid style]
        (axis cs:\x,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
        (axis cs:\x,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});}
    \temp
}
%               v-- first, second and last y-positions for middle grid
\foreach \y in {0.5,1.5,...,4.5}{ % <-- modified these as well
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[middle grid style]
        (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\y) --
        (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\y);}
    \temp
}
\end{pgfonlayer}

%\addplot    [mark = none, domain= 0:10, smooth]{1.1*x};
\node[below] at (-0.2,0) {$O$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```